# Ambiguity with inheriting an optional-parameter base method

Tags: c#, inheritance, c#-4.0

I have a base class with one optional default parameter, which a child class automatically provides a value for:

```
public class Merchant
{
    public string WriteResults(List<string> moreFields = null)
    {

        List<string> ListOfObjects = new List<string>() {Name, Address};
        if (moreFields != null)
        {
            ListOfObjects.AddRange(moreFields);
        }
            return ListOfObjects.ToString() //not real output
}


public class SpecificMerchant : Merchant 
{   
    new public string WriteResults()
        {
            return ((Merchant)this).WriteResults(new List<string>() {
                    Address, Phone //class-specific parameters
            });
        }
}
```

I used the `new` keyword when calling `SpecificMerchant.WriteResults` because both the parent and the base can take no parameters, but the compiler says this is unnecessary:

> The member 'SpecificMerchant.WriteResults()' does not hide an
>   inherited member. The new keyword is not required.

Why? Aren't I, in practice, overriding the parent method?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx -- in particular, see part three of the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because optional parameters are a compile time construct, not a runtime construct.

Your base class is always going to have a method with one parameter.  The compiler just "substitutes" null *at compile time* if you call that method without an argument.

That being said, I would avoid trying to do what you're implementing above.  Even if you remove the `new` keyword, which will let it compile, you're adding a lot of confusion.  I would, personally, make the base class implementation virtual, if required, or add two methods to the base class and override one instead of using optional arguments.

For a good resource, I'd recommend reading [James Michael Hare's post on Optional Parameters](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/06/17/c-optional-parameters---pros-and-pitfalls.aspx) - He discusses the pitfalls, like this one, when you mix optional arguments with inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not overriding it. You're providing a method with a different signature. Consider this:

```
new SpecificMerchant().WriteResults(new List<string>());
```

Could that *possibly* call the method in `SpecificMerchant`? No - you've specified an argument, and `SpecificMerchant.WriteResults` doesn't specify any parameters. That fact alone shows that it couldn't possibly override `Merchant.WriteResults`.

Your code could certainly cause confusion, as overloading in a type hierarchy often does even *without* optional parameters - but as far as the C# compiler and the CLR are concerned, these are very different methods... It so happens that both would be validate for a call with no arguments specified, but that's a different matter.